Getters for multidimensional arrays
I was wondering how to exactly do a getter for a multidimensional array. I have a class (called Figure), one of its attributes is a bidimenisonal array (matrix), and I want to read that matrix from another class that contains a Figure object.
I thought it would be a good option to use a getter to return a constant pointer to the matrix, but, despite I know how to do that in a normal array, the IDE warns me that I cannot do it, because I am returning something that it is not a pointer:
const int SIZE = 5;

class Figure
{
public:
...
    const int* getMatrix() const {return m_matrix;};
...
private:
...
    int m_matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
...
}

I guess the problem here is that using a matrix requires to know how many columns the matrix has (as far as I know), because the compiler need to know where the second row starts, so I guess that "m_matrix" is not only a pointer to the beginning of the array, but it contains the information of the number of columns too (I am not sure, I am only trying to understand the error). Anyways, I don't know how I would return that type of pointer if I wanted (I don't want, as I am going to explain next, but I am curious to know how I would do it :))
Furthermore, I am afraid that returning the pointer it's going to violate the encapsulation of data (I have seen some posts talking about this), I mean, if I give acces to the exact part of the memory where my matrix is being stored, the matrix could be changed outside the class Figure, and that shouldn't happen.
So, the only thing that comes to my mind, is to use a getter to return only one position of the matrix, and then, using a for loop to make a copy of the matrix.
const int SIZE = 5;

class Figure
{
public:
...
    int getMatrix(int i, int j) const {return m_matrix[i][j];};
... 
private:
...
    int m_matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
...
}

Is there something better to solve it?

Remember that arrays decay to pointers to their first element. So return m_matrix; is the same as return &m_matrix[0];. That that's a pointer to an array of SIZE elements. So the type is int (*)[SIZE].

For a matrix-like data structure like you have, it seems to be quite common to overload the operator() function. As in int operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const { return m_matrix[x][y]; } and int& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) { return m_matrix[x][y]; }

Write a class to encapsulate your matrix. Then getMatrix can return a reference to your matrix class.

For copying of Figure objects, there's really nothing you need to do for the matrix. The default-generated copy-constructor and copy assignment operator will work fine.

int m_matrix[SIZE][SIZE]; --> #include <array> -- using MatrixType = std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE>; and then MatrixType m_matrix;.  With that you are not dealing with pointers.

I would use a single dimensional std::array to entire allocation, then create pipe through views::chunk.

C++23 will get this out of the box. You might also be interested in std::mdspan

From a design point of view : A figure should have a matrix class as member not a raw 2D array

A class should either be a buisness logic or resource management, not a combination of both. Your Figure class looks like it is doing both. Abstract the Matrix into its own class then return a const reference to the matrix.

Step #1: use C++ arrays, and not C arrays.

"Is there something better to solve it?"
Example of a matrix class (c++20):
//concept for trait std::is_arithmetic
template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic<T>;

//generic 2D matrix
template <Arithmetic T, size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
requires ((Rows > 0) && (Cols > 0)) //avoid uncomplete type
class matrix {
public:

    using type       = matrix<T, Rows, Cols>; //type of matrix
    using value_type = T;                     //type of data

    //default ctor and copy ctor
    constexpr matrix()            = default;
    constexpr matrix(const type&) = default;

    //initialization ctor
    //allows mixed arithmetic types as args
    //e.g. matrix<float,2,2>{
    //         1, 0,
    //         0, 1
    //     };
    template <Arithmetic... Args>
    requires (sizeof...(Args) == (Rows*Cols)) //amount of args must match matrix size
    constexpr matrix(Args... args) noexcept
    : m_data{static_cast<value_type>(args)...} {} //unfold to proper type

    //number of elements in data
    constexpr size_t size()       noexcept { return Rows*Cols; }
    constexpr size_t size() const noexcept { return Rows*Cols; }

    //returns a pointer to the first element
    //e.g. used for conversion
    constexpr       value_type* data()       noexcept { return &(m_data[0][0]); }
    constexpr const value_type* data() const noexcept { return &(m_data[0][0]); }
    
    //explicit conversion operator
    //e.g. static_cast<value_type*>(matrix)
    explicit constexpr operator       value_type*()       noexcept { return data(); }
    explicit constexpr operator const value_type*() const noexcept { return data(); }

    //subscript operator
    //e.g. matrix(row, col)
    constexpr value_type& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) noexcept
    { 
        return m_data[row][col];
    }
    constexpr const value_type& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const noexcept
    { 
        return m_data[row][col];
    }

private:

    //the 'real' (row major) matrix
    value_type m_data[Rows][Cols];

};

